# Why adding lock.unlock before condition_variable.wait_for causes thread to block in following loop?

Tags: c++, thread-safety

I try to write simple timer class using observer pattern. I stumbled upon one particular problem, I do not have a clue why unlocking lock before condition_variable.wait_for() causes mutex to be locked at the beginning of next loop.

My code looks like this

```
class LittleTimer {
public:
    using ObserverData = std::tuple< std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point, std::function<void()> >;
    LittleTimer() : running_(false) {}

    ~LittleTimer() {
        Stop();
    }

    void
    AddObserver(std::chrono::milliseconds  interval,
                std::function<void()>      callback)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        auto scheduled_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + interval;
        observers_.push(ObserverData(scheduled_time, std::move(callback)));
        lock.unlock();
        condition_.notify_one();
    }

    void Start() {
        if (!running_) {
            running_ = true;
            thread_ = std::thread([this]() {
                    while (running_)
                    {
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
                        if(!observers_.empty()) {
                            auto next_observer = observers_.top();
                            auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
                            if(std::get< 0 >(next_observer) <= now) { // check top event scheduled time
                                auto observer = observers_.top();
                                observers_.pop();
                                lock.unlock();
                                // call the observer's callback
                                auto callback = std::get< 1 >(observer);
                                callback();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                auto sleep_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::get< 0 >(next_observer) - now);
                                // lock.unlock(); // !!!!!!!!!!!!!! if this is active, in the next loop code is blocked on creation of lock
                                condition_.wait_for(lock, sleep_time);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            condition_.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    void Stop() {
        if (running_) {
            running_ = false;
            condition_.notify_one();  // notify to wake up the thread and allow it to exit
            if (thread_.joinable())
            {
                thread_.join();
            }
        }
    }

private:

    struct ObserverComparator
    {
        bool operator()(const ObserverData& left, const ObserverData& right) const {
            return std::get< 0 >(left) > std::get< 0 >(right);
        }
    };
    
    // data
    std::priority_queue< ObserverData, std::vector< ObserverData >, ObserverComparator >  observers_;
    // synchro
    std::thread                                                                           thread_;
    std::mutex                                                                            mutex_;
    std::condition_variable                                                               condition_;
    // smooth closing
    bool                                                                                  running_;
};
```

My question concerns lock.unlock() call just before calling wait_for (marked with !!!!!!) on condition_variable. This line come up from online examples. When this line is active following loop stops at the creation of lock at the beginning of while. It looks like underlying mutex is lock there. Removing this line make whole code work as intended.

W.

PS. simple test i use looks like this

```
class Observer {
public:
    virtual void OnTimerTick() = 0;
};

class TimerObserver : public Observer {
public:
    TimerObserver(const std::string& name) : name_(name), ticks_(0) {}

    void OnTimerTick() override {
        std::cout << "Observer " << name_ << " notified\n";
    }

private:
    std::string name_;
};

main()
{
    timerobserver::LittleTimer timer;

    TimerObserver observer1("uno");
    TimerObserver observer2("due");
    
    timer.AddObserver(std::chrono::milliseconds(60), [&observer1]() {
        observer1.OnTimerTick();
    });

    timer.Start();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));

    timer.AddObserver(std::chrono::milliseconds(10), [&observer2]() {
        observer2.OnTimerTick();
    });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(60));

    timer.Stop();
}
```

Comment: You must ALWAYS wait on a condition variable from within a lock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for):

> Calling this function if `lock.mutex()` is not locked by the current thread is undefined behavior.

You must have `lock` locked to call `condition_.wait_for(lock, sleep_time);`.